# Laravel search query for user's friends

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am confused with what should be the search query to find the friends of particular user.

I have created a pivot table for friends relationship.

friends Table

```
id
sender
recipient
```

user table

```
id
name
email
password
etc...
```

Please guide what should be the search query for friends for particular user.

Comment: How these both tables are related to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a many to many relation with itself

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function friends()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'friends', 'sender', 'recipient');
    }
}
```

And for use it

```
$friends = User::find(3)->friends;
```

Or filter the friends called Jon

```
$friends = User::find(3)->friends()->where('name', 'Jon')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the models set up then its simply:

```
User::friends();
```

The friends() function describes the relation between User model and Friend model in this example.

Example of User model The second argument in belongsToMany function is the pivot table name:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function friends()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Friend", "user_friend");
    }
}
```

Example of friend model (can be used to query in inverse).

```
class Friend extends Model
{
    public function friends()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\User", "user_friend");
    }
}
```